# Как обратиться к элементу XAML с помощью C# в WPF приложении?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Для примера есть 2 кнопки с разным контентом

```
<Button Name="ToggleButton" Height="40" Width="40" Cursor="Hand" Style="{DynamicResource PlayerButton}">
    <Grid Width="10" Height="15" >
        <Path Name="ToggleButtonPath" Data="M8 5v14l11-7z" Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" Height="15" Width="11"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
<Button Name="NextButton" Height="40" Width="40" Cursor="Hand" Style="{DynamicResource PlayerButton}">
    <Grid Width="10" Height="15">
        <Path Name="NextButtonPath" Data="M8 5v14l11-7z" Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" Height="15" Width="11"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Отличаются в кнопках только Path.

Как можно реализовать программу так, чтобы не нужно было прописывать для каждого Path своё имя, но можно было изменять Path.

Для примера через имя кнопки ToggleButton.Path.Fill = ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы помещаете что-то внутрь тега `Button` - на самом деле вы устанавливаете этой кнопке свойство `Content`, соответственно через `Content` и можно попробовать добраться до нужного элемента. Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
((Path)((Grid)Button.Content).Children[0]).Fill = ...
```

Но я вам не рекомендую так делать, ведь это, во-первых, не удобно и громоздко, во-вторых, не надежно, т.к. фактически дерево элементов может отличаться от того, что вы видите в разметке

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Видимо у меня разметка не очень адекватная... Может подскажите что нужно сделать для того чтобы было практично, красиво и надежно? Может перенести Content в стиль кнопки и работать уже со стилем, если это возможно?

Comment: А что вы в итоге получить-то хотите? Почему обращаться к `Path` по имени вам не нравится?

Comment: Потому что в программе много таких кнопок, но я уже нашёл подходящее мне решение благодоря вам, спасибо большое.
Получился такой код с использованием имён  
Button but = sender as Button;  
((Path)but.FindName(but.Name+"Path")).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(97,97,97));

Answer (score 2):

Я бы оформил ваш код в виде стиля. Заодно не нужно дублировать код с контентом:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="PlayerButton">
    <!-- тут ваш старый стиль -->
</Style>
<!-- это будет ваш новый стиль -->
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="PlayerButtonEx" BasedOn="{StaticResource PlayerButton}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Grid Width="10" Height="15" >
                <!-- цвет Fill берём из свойства Foreground кнопки -->
                <Path Data="M8 5v14l11-7z"
                      Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                 AncestorType=Button}}"
                      Stretch="Fill" Height="15" Width="11"/>
            </Grid>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Использовать так:

```
<Button Name="ToggleButton" Style="{DynamicResource PlayerButtonEx}" Foreground="Blue"/>
<Button Name="NextButton" Style="{DynamicResource PlayerButtonEx}" Foreground="Blue"/>
```